# How to find div with text with contains in xpath

Tags: c#, xpath, webdriver

I'm using webdriver and C# and I have this div:

```
<div class="dijitTreeRow dijitInline dijitTreeRowSelected" 
     role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="rowNode" 
     title="TestPage, ID: 114 (Type: M)">
```

How can I find this element with contains? The ID is dynamic so, I can't always look for it with the whole string just with the beginning "Testpage".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this XPath :

```
//div[starts-with(@title, 'TestPage')]
```

or using `contains()` :

```
//div[contains(@title, 'TestPage')]
```

Comment: Do you mean like: Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@title, 'TestPage')]"));